# Making trails in a curve mesh created by the Animation Nodes add-on

Tags: bezier-curves, animation-nodes, fcurves

I've asked the question before in here: [Creating trails using Animation Nodes by delaying the frame of the following polygons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128940/creating-trails-using-animation-nodes-by-delaying-the-frame-of-the-following-pol) . This was for making trails, but for objects only. I realized I want to do it with a curve that was hooked by two empty objects. Since Animation Nodes is not (yet) observing curve hooks, I can't apply the same  method suggested by Omar. I've also tried my first solution [image]

But it didn't get what I've expected, for the curve is changing over time. Here's the result:

[image]

The solution that I've come in mind is to create a spline/curve using the add-on to avoid hooking so I could make trails in it by instancing the previous frames. But the question I have in mind now is: Would I be able to create this trails, and filling a polygon between them. (Additional question: If it's possible, how do I fill up with polygons between the created curve edges), if it's not possible, what method could you recommend to create trails in a hooked curve.
[Animation Nodes - Animated object trail](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45838/animation-nodes-animated-object-trail#) I've found this article that could help me create this, but I realized it's has a long method so I decided to ask a question first before doing it. Here's the nodes to create curve between two object (there could be a better method than this): [image]

Blend file: [image]

I'm currently using Animation nodes 2.0 in blender 2.79b, but you can answer me in Animation nodes 2.1

**EDIT**

Now I've tried to do making it myself with Omar's answer, I've tried to loop over the frames using float range in the time info node and plug it into the frame input of "object transforms input" to get the previous transforms of the two empty points I've made. (That's why I used AN 2.0 because it has frame input in object transforms input node unlike AN 2.1) 
Now I have the vector list of the previous locations of my two empty points, I don't know how would I connect the spline according to indices of the vector lists, and connect it to "spline from points" node. Here's the nodes: (This maybe wrong XD)

If it is possible to achieve the desired result without the said frame input, it's welcome to be accepted. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You say you implemented hooks proceduraly, consequently you can construct the spline at any frame of your choosing. So, what you need to do is loop over the frames, construct the spline, evaluate some points onto it, and append those points. The loop will output a list containing the evaluate points at all frames. All you need to do now is construct a mesh from that by using the edge and polygon indices of the grid node as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: I guess you would like to do this my own for me to learn. I'll accept the answer if the idea you gave works!! :) Thank you

Comment: Omar I really can't get what you've said "loop over the frames" and then the rest. I ask for a hint because i can't deeply understand working with loops (with my young age). I end up with this https://gyazo.com/6acb281f83eaeb69e6d03ab9e99dd336 . I already have the vector list with it's previous transforms using "float range" node and "frame" in "object transforms input", but I don't know how could I sort the list according to their index of the list, so I would connect the vector list of the first point uniformly to the second point. I hope you would respond :') thanks.

Comment: @WorshipLyrics I built this answer based on my other answer you linked. You are using a legacy AN version and a completely different workflow. So drop the legacy AN version you are using and implement the example we created in the other answer first, then come back and implement this.

Comment: I'm not really certain of what you've said, but I hope this is what you mean't